# Incorrect Results - OpenCL on Intel HD 4000

Tags: c, macos, opencl, intel, gpgpu

Apple included the latest Intel OpenCL drivers with Mavericks, which includes OpenCL support for integrated GPUs (Yay!).  CPU support was already there.  Anyway, I figured I'd try it out on my MacBook.  I took the following simple vector addition example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>

// OpenCL kernel. Each work item takes care of one element of c
const char *kernelSource =                                       "\n" \
"#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable                    \n" \
"__kernel void vecAdd(  __global double *a,                       \n" \
"                       __global double *b,                       \n" \
"                       __global double *c,                       \n" \
"                       const unsigned int n)                    \n" \
"{                                                               \n" \
"    //Get our global thread ID                                  \n" \
"    int id = get_global_id(0);                                  \n" \
"                                                                \n" \
"    //Make sure we do not go out of bounds                      \n" \
"    if (id < n)                                                 \n" \
"        c[id] = a[id] + b[id];                                  \n" \
"}                                                               \n" \
                                                                "\n" ;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // Length of vectors
    unsigned int n = 100000;

    // Host input vectors
    double *h_a;
    double *h_b;
    // Host output vector
    double *h_c;

    // Device input buffers
    cl_mem d_a;
    cl_mem d_b;
    // Device output buffer
    cl_mem d_c;

    cl_platform_id cpPlatform;        // OpenCL platform
    cl_device_id device_id;           // device ID
    cl_context context;               // context
    cl_command_queue queue;           // command queue
    cl_program program;               // program
    cl_kernel kernel;                 // kernel

    // Size, in bytes, of each vector
    size_t bytes = n * sizeof(double);

    // Allocate memory for each vector on host
    h_a = (double*) malloc(bytes);
    h_b = (double*) malloc(bytes);
    h_c = (double*) malloc(bytes);

    // Initialize vectors on host
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        h_a[i] = sinf(i) * sinf(i);
        h_b[i] = cosf(i) * cosf(i);
    }

    size_t globalSize, localSize;
    cl_int err;

    // Number of work items in each local work group
    localSize = 64;

    // Number of total work items - localSize must be devisor
    globalSize = ceil(n / (float) localSize) * localSize;

    // Bind to platform
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &cpPlatform, NULL);

    // Get ID for the device
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(cpPlatform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);

    // Create a context  
    context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);

    // Create a command queue 
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);

    // Create the compute program from the source buffer
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &kernelSource, NULL, &err);

    // Build the program executable 
    clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vecAdd", &err);

    // Create the input and output arrays in device memory for our calculation
    d_a = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);
    d_b = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);
    d_c = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, bytes, NULL, NULL);

    // Write our data set into the input array in device memory
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, d_a, CL_TRUE, 0, bytes, h_a, 0, NULL, NULL);
    err |= clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, d_b, CL_TRUE, 0, bytes, h_b, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Set the arguments to our compute kernel
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_a);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_b);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_c);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(unsigned int), &n);

    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of the data set  
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalSize, &localSize, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Wait for the command queue to get serviced before reading back results
    clFinish(queue);

    // Read the results from the device
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, d_c, CL_TRUE, 0, bytes, h_c, 0, NULL, NULL );

    //Sum up vector c and print result divided by n, this should equal 1 within error
    double sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += h_c[i];

    printf("final result: %lf\n", sum / (double) n);

    // release OpenCL resources
    clReleaseMemObject(d_a);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_b);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_c);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    //release host memory
    free(h_a);
    free(h_b);
    free(h_c);

    return 0;
}
```

and ran it on the HD 4000 chip on my MacBook 9,2 (which has an i7-3520M).  It ran and finished without complaining, but, very oddly, it produced incorrect results on the GPU.  This code is supposed to return a number very close to one, but the final result from the GPU is 40.726689.  When I run the same code on the CPU using OpenCL (or on other OpenCL systems), it returns 1.000000.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?  Am I missing something, or are there limitations to the OpenCL implementation or the graphics processor?  My first thought was memory, but the example uses less than a megabyte, so it shouldn't be that.

EDIT:

May have just answered my own question: I switched the example to using single instead of double precision, and it returned correct results.  Can someone confirm the HD 4000 supports single, but not double precision?  Also, why wouldn't the compiler complain if double precision isn't supported?

Comment: I'm a CUDA guy and not very experienced with OpenCL. But I think you'd better check if `clEnqueueReadBuffer` is synchronized or not. You may need to manually wait for it to finish.

Comment: You don't need the continuation character (\\) to concatenate strings.

Comment: The OpenCL example is from the Oak Ridge National Lab knowledge base, so we can assume it's correct OpenCL usage.  I do know a bit of OpenCL (and a lot of CUDA), but I didn't originally write the example.

Comment: The the third argument to clEnqueue{Read,Write}Buffer is the blocking flag and is passed CL_TRUE; hence, they are synchronous ops.  Have you checked the error flags?

Comment: I should point out that, even though error codes are being collected, they are not being checked.  Please check the error codes, that would save some trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This appears to be a bug with Apple's OpenCL implementation. According to `clGetDeviceInfo(..., CL_DEVICE_VERSION, ...)`, the Intel HD4000 supports OpenCL 1.2 under OS X 10.9. This means that it *has* to support double precision, since this is a core feature as of OpenCL 1.2. I've just tested an even simpler double precision kernel on my own HD4000, and it's just completely broken. I'll be filing a bug against this, but if you wish to do the same, you can use the [Apple Bug Reporting System](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).</strike>

You shouldn't need to enable the `cl_khr_fp64` extension using `#pragma` in your kernel either, but removing this causes the program to fail to build (which is also a bug).

I was mistaken when writing the above - double precision was changed from an optional extension to a core optional feature in OpenCL 1.2; it is not mandatory to support it. You can query whether a particular device supports double precision by calling `clGetDeviceInfo(..., CL_DEVICE_DOUBLE_FP_CONFIG, ...)` and checking for a non-zero value (which indicates that it is indeed supported). I've just tried this on a HD4000 under OS X and it returns `0`.

That said, if double precision isn't supported, I'd expect the compiler to throw an error when trying to compile a kernel that uses it, so this is still a bug in my book.

Comment: For reference: It does. The main problem with the code shown is the lack of error-code checking. Maybe one could also highlight that the OpenCL compiler complains (at "runtime"). Not the C++ compiler compiling the host program